# Getting data from firebase with JS and putting into a object

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, function, firebase-realtime-database

When I'm trying to get data from firebase, i can and I get the data, but when I asign de data to an Object(var) to update it, it throw me an error. I want to update the color from a color picker library named "IRO".

There is an example for the 5 color pickers that I set:

> /* CREAR SELECTOR DE COLOR */
>
> ```
>     var atras = new iro.ColorPicker("#ledAtras", {
>         width: 150,
>         color: "#f00"
>     });
> ```

And the code to update it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ // AL CARGAR EL DOCUNENTO 
            var search = "/";
            updateUI(search); // LAMAR A LA FUNCCION

        }); // FIN FUNCCION


        function updateUI(search) {  // FUNCCION PARA ACTUALIZAR VALORES EN TIEMPO REAL

            db.ref(search).on("value",function(snap){ // ACCEDER A LA UBICACION RECIBIDA Y RECOGER LA INFORMACION EN UN OBJETO JSON
                derecha = snap.val().derecha; // COGER EL VALOR LED DERECHA DEL JSON
                medio = snap.val().medio; // COGER EL VALOR LED ATRAS DEL JSON
                izquierda = snap.val().izquierda; // COGER EL VALOR LED IZQUIERDA DEL JSON
                lamparaDer = snap.val().lamparaDer; // COGER EL VALOR LED LAMPARA DER DEL JSON
                lamparaIzq = snap.val().lamparaIzq; // COGER EL VALOR LED LAMPARE IZQ DEL JSON
                console.log(derecha);console.log(medio);console.log(izquierda);console.log(lamparaDer);console.log(lamparaIzq);
                updateColor(derecha, medio, izquierda, lamparaDer, lamparaIzq);

            }); //FIN DEL ACCESO A LA DB


        } // FI FUNCCION


        function updateColor(derecha, medio, izquierda, lamparaDer, lamparaIzq){ /* actualizar al color de la base de datos */
            derecha.color.hexString = "#" + atras; document.getElementById(ledAtras).style.color = "#" + derecha.toString(); // ACTUALIZAR LED ATRAS 
            atras.color.hexString = "#" + medio; document.getElementById(ledAtras).style.color = "#" + medio; // ACTUALIZAR LED medio 
            izquierda.color.hexString = "#" + izquierda; document.getElementById(ledAtras).style.color = "#" + izquierda; // ACTUALIZAR LED izquierda 
            lamparaDer.color.hexString = "#" + lamparaDer; document.getElementById(ledAtras).style.color = "#" + lamparaDer; // ACTUALIZAR LED ATRAS 
            lamparaIzq.color.hexString = "#" + lamparaIzq; document.getElementById(ledAtras).style.color = "#" + lamparaIzq; // ACTUALIZAR LED ATRAS 
            $( "#warpLoad" ).fadeOut( "slow" ) // QUITAR ANIMACION DE CARGA
            $( "#panelBody:hidden" ).first().fadeIn( "slow" ); // ENSEÑAR CONTENIDO
        }
```

The console log throw me:

> ```
> >    VM15216:68 FFF0FF
> >     VM15216:68 FFFFFF
> >     VM15216:68 FFFFFF
> >     VM15216:68 f0f0f0
> >     VM15216:68 f2f2f2
> >     util.js:189 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot set property 'hexString' of undefined
> >         at updateColor (<anonymous>:78:37)
> >         at <anonymous>:69:17
> >         at https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:119160
> >         at Object.t.exceptionGuard (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:5424)
> >         at e.raise (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:154608)
> >         at e.si (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:154261)
> >         at e.raiseEventsForChangedPath (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:154083)
> >         at e.ee (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:38632)
> >         at t.It (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:91077)
> >         at t.wt (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.7.0/firebase.js:20:90986) 
> >     t.warn @ util.js:189
> >     (anonymous) @ util.js:566
> >     setTimeout (async)
> >     t.exceptionGuard @ util.js:560
> >     e.raise @ EventQueue.js:158
> >     e.si @ EventQueue.js:111
> >     e.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ EventQueue.js:95
> >     e.ee @ Repo.js:200
> >     t.It @ PersistentConnection.js:458
> >     t.wt @ PersistentConnection.js:452
> >     e.wt @ Connection.js:262
> >     e.sn @ Connection.js:256
> >     (anonymous) @ Connection.js:157
> >     t.xn @ WebSocketConnection.js:197
> >     t.handleIncomingFrame @ WebSocketConnection.js:247
> >     mySock.onmessage @ WebSocketConnection.js:144
> >      
> >      util.js:567 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'hexString' of undefined
> >         at updateColor (<anonymous>:78:37)
> >         at <anonymous>:69:17
> >         at EventRegistration.js:65
> >         at Object.t.exceptionGuard (util.js:556)
> >         at e.raise (EventQueue.js:158)
> >         at e.si (EventQueue.js:111)
> >         at e.raiseEventsForChangedPath (EventQueue.js:95)
> >         at e.ee (Repo.js:200)
> >         at t.It (PersistentConnection.js:458)
> >         at t.wt (PersistentConnection.js:452)
> ```

I want to get the variable from firebase and update the color(it works when is not in the function snap) or to get out the var from the snap and set it after the updateUI function.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `derecha.hexString` without `.color`?

Comment: no becouse you say what value do you want to edit and in wich value: edit the color with ex value, or rgb or anything else